# How can you access a secondary calendar with cfexchangeconnection?

Tags: coldfusion, calendar, exchange-server

I have an Exchange account with multiple calendars defined. Is it possible to query a secondary calendar with cfexchangeconnection?

Here's the code that I use to get the primary calendar, but I don't see any options in CF8 to talk to the secondary calendar "AltCal" in my profile.

```
<cfexchangeConnection action="open" username="#theusername#" password="#pw#" server="#exchangeServerIP#" connection="theConnection" protocol="https" >

    <cfexchangecalendar action="get" name="qEvents" connection="theConnection">
        <cfexchangefilter name="maxrows" value="100">
        <cfexchangefilter name="StartTime" from="#CreateDate(2009,5,8)#" to="#CreateDate(2009,5,8)#">
        <cfexchangefilter name="allDayEvent" value="0">
    </cfexchangecalendar>
<cfexchangeConnection action="close" connection="theConnection">
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I took a close look at the [CFML Reference](http://cfquickdocs.com/cf8/?getDoc=cfexchangecalendar) and the [User Guide](http://livedocs.adobe.com/coldfusion/8/htmldocs/cfexchange_1.html), and it looks like this is something that's not supported.

I suggest you [enter this as a feature request](http://www.adobe.com/go/wish). I would vote for it!

Comment: Submitted as feature request. Didn't receive an ID, but if/when I do, I'll add it here.

Comment: I'm not positive but I think Adobe just counts multiple submissions about the same topic as votes for one another. They are supposed to be opening up a public bug tracker (and one can only assume feature requests included) soon. In the meantime, if you leave a comment with roughly what you submitted, I'll submit the same.

Answer (score 0):

Worst case you should be able to access what you like through .NET/COM cfobject calls.  Of course doing might be an exercise in intermestingness.

This might be of use to ya..

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms878108.aspx